# Exclude files by extension for time machine backup

Tags: backup, time-machine

I'm using Time Machine to back up all my software development files.

By default it backs up ALL the files and folders, which results in the object files being backed up each time the code is compiled.

But I would like to exclude "built" files (similar to `git` and its `.gitignore` file)

Is there a way to configure time machine to exclude, say, `*.o` and `*.d` ?

Comment: No - However you could do like many build systems like Xcode, Jetbrains, Cmake do and put the build artifacts into a different directory - e.g. Xcode in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data

Comment: Thanks. That's disappointing.